# Making a programming paradigm

Tags: paradigms

What are the steps of making a programming paradigm?

If you like, please give some light illustration on the procedural programming paradigm. Also, I'd love to be referred to some light/introductory/overall-view texts.

Answer (score 1):

Find a problem that needs solving which no other available paradigm addresses well and figure out a solution.  Not trivial, but good luck! ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's not such a simple thing to do... Object Orientated programming is a paradigm, as is procedural programming and Aspect Orientated programming. So the short answer is: start off with a damn fine idea and proceed from there.

I got started in procedural programming using Pascal but that was a long time ago so there's probably something more appropriate these days. Maybe play with scripting a bit to get a feel for it. Python's friendly and you can pretend it's procedural if you want to.